# Настройка Laravel+Nginx в Debian. Роутинг

Tags: laravel

Не работает даже

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

в файле web.php - возвращает 404.

Laravel 5.4

Comment: А конфиг nginx где?

Comment: уже нашел решение.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается добавлением в файл /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
следующих строк:

```
root /srv/www/project/public/;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```